# echo php result in the javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, jplayer

i'm trying to echo some result in php in the javascript but it keeps not working messing up the interface of the javascript player

that's the full javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    new jPlayerPlaylist({


        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, [
            {
                title:"Name",
                mp3:"audio.mp3",
            },      

        ], {
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "oga, mp3",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

i want to replace this :

```
            {
                title:"Name",
                mp3:"audio.mp3",
            },
```

with this :

```
    while(
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $sender = $row['sender'];
    $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
    $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
    $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
    echo '{<br/>title:"' . $sender_fullname . '",<br/>mp3:"link",<br/>},';  
}
```

it's a while loop i need it to get all the results

can anyone pls help in how to replace it ?
thanks

Comment: try jquery.php.it is a jquery plugin that lets you use php within javascript.I've found it recently.so it is an offer to try.link: https://github.com/Xaxis/jquery.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yet another solution. You could do:

```
<?php
    $playlist = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $sender = $row['sender'];
        $sender_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = '$sender'");
        $sender_name = mysql_fetch_object($sender_name_query);
        $sender_fullname = $sender_name->fullname;
        $playlist[] = (object) array(
            'title' => $sender_fullname,
            'mp3' => 'audio.mp3'
        );  
    }   
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, 
        <?php echo(json_encode($playlist));?>,
        {
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "oga, mp3",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: no its a while loop i need it to get all the results

Comment: see my update. You didn't mention what your loop was doing so I made a generic looking one to help you out

Comment: result undefined ?? :/

Comment: y the result is still undefined :/ ??

Comment: thank you Omar, but it should have this form  ` {
                title:"Name",
                mp3:"audio.mp3",
            },`
i think this is y its giving undefined

Comment: See my edit. I casted the playlist array elements to an object using `(object)`. That should get it in the form `[{title: "NAME", mp3: "audio.mp3"}]` which is what I think you need. I'm getting the correct output so if its not working for you just make sure that you copy/pasted correctly

Comment: glad it worked. Make sure to check the green check mark and select the answer if it indeed did answer your question.

Comment: Omar in the loop it gets the names of the all the senders but get also the name of the user himself :/ y is that ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

`<br/>` isn't valid in javascript. Try:

```
echo '{\ntitle:"' . $sender_fullname . '",\nmp3:"link",\n},';
```

Comment: bad idea. you **NEVER** dump bare strings into a javascript context. a single `'` or other metacharacter in that string and you've killed the entire JS code block. **ALWAYS** dump via `echo json_encode(...)` instead, to guarantee syntactically correct JS.

Comment: can u pls tell me how ? MARC B

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<br>` tags, use `\n` instead to add newlines (if you really need it, script will work without linebreaks).

You cant use HTML tags in javascript

Comment: Then its your js code that is wrong, check for errors!

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    title: "<?php echo json_encode($sender_fullname);?>",
    mp3: "audio.mp3",
},
```

Comment: no its a while loop i need it to get all the results

Comment: Sure! Cleaner solution!